# callback url for tel:

Tags: iphone, telephony

I am using `tel:{phone-number}` to initiate call from my application.

I want to know if I can set a callback url for my application, so that once the call ends My Application starts (resumes) again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about using a callback, but you can use a UIWebView to make a call without leaving your app.  In this case `escapedPhoneNumber` is an `NSString` containing the number you want to call:

```
NSURL *telURL = 
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", 
                        escapedPhoneNumber]];

// using a UIWebView here allows us to make a call without leaving the App
UIWebView * callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:callWebview];
[callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```